# Progress Bar with Added Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have to build a kind of progress/counter/meter bar in a webpage.
[image: Bar]

Basicly I'll be getting the data (total number of hours, in this case 500h and number of hours avaiable, 400h in the example) from JSON and load the bar accordingly.

I've tried to adapt jqueryUI and bootstrap progress bars, but I'm getting stuck when implementing the circle with the avaiable hours.

Using bootstrap structure

```
<div class="progress">
  <div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0">
    <span id="pProgress"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="circleProgress" class="progress-bar transBar" role="progressbar">
    <span id="pCircle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since bootstrap can stack bars, I had the ideia to, instead of a second bar, it could be the circle, so it would follow the progress bar, but since the progress div has a height, the circle gets cut.
Tried with position absolute, but got no where.

Also tried placing the circle on a second div, parallel with the class="progress", but couldn't figure out a way to calculate the progressbar position.

So I'm looking for any tips, solutions or places to find a solution to solve my problem.

*edit*
Sorry for the lack of details,
made a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hmt0L07r/1/

I'm really new at using fiddle, so I'm not sure how to add the image that i was using for the circle, but basicly it would only show the top of the circle inside the light grey bar.

Comment: Can you create a demo of it?

Comment: Consider using this addon
http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo.html
and changing a little the skin.

Comment: Have a look at the material design light progressbars ->  http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#loading-section/progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a rough progressbar on jsfiddle. Its pretty simple, use the date you get from the JSON via ajax and do some math an than adding them to the element. With some css3 you could also animate the whole bar.

```
var reachedh = 233,
    totalh = 500,
    availableh = 400,
    reachedhPercent = (reachedh / totalh)*100,
    availablehPercent = (availableh / totalh)*100;


$('#pProgress').css({'width':reachedhPercent+'%'});
$('#availableh').css({'left':availablehPercent+'%'});
$('#availableh').text(availableh+'h');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jnn6sqj/

**EDIT:**
Fiddle with basic styling and animation. Also I added the bar of available hours, i just saw the bubble before.
http://jsfiddle.net/5jnn6sqj/1/

Comment: This got me to the solution, after a bit of tweaks and adapting the JS.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a good website, and I found http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress. This website may come in handy.
Try doing

    `<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
    </div>
    </div>`